# How can I access the xaml of a silverlight application from the browser?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I am trying to automate tests for a silverlight application on a browser, and I need to be able to get the XAML content of the silverlight application, while it's running on the browser.

How can I achieve this?

*Let me start over again.*

*I'm a QA and I have the task of writing black-box UI automation scripts for my company's Silverlight app. The tests will input values in textfields, click on buttons and read output.
The problem I currently have, is that I cannot access to the elements within the Silverlight app.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for UI unit testing then have a look at [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/04/02/unit-testing-with-silverlight.aspx) on Scott Guthrie's blog.

Automated UI testing is going to be part of [Silverlight 5](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/02/announcing-silverlight-5.aspx), but in the meantime Telerik offer automated Silverlight UI testing in their [Web UI Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/products/webui-test-studio-developer-edition.aspx).

If you're just after something with which you can inspect and grab XAML, then [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/download-silverlight-spy) does exactly that.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not looking for unit testing.
The information concerning Silverlight 5 is very useful though and also Web UI Test Studio is the paid tool I have been looking at.

Thank you Town.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you mean the following. Your SL app is MyApp.xaml and you want the URL like: 
http://www.mydomain.com/MyApp.xaml?

`Application.Current.Host.Source.AbsoluteUri`

For more info see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.host%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: Afraid not. If the SL app has the following xaml,

<Path Stroke="Black" Fill="Gray">
  <Path.Data>
    <PathGeometry Figures="M 10,100 C 10,300 300,-200 300,100" />
  </Path.Data>
</Path>

i want to be able to see it.

Comment: I have Edited my question. I hope it makes more sense now.